# How can I customize the Y-Axis on individual panels using ggplot2 with facet_grid in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph data using facet_grid with the following code:

```
ggplot() +               
  geom_point(data = graph2_old_longer, aes(x=Distance,y=concentration, col= factor(Year)))+scale_color_discrete(name="")+
  labs(y="Concentration (mg/L)")+labs(x="Distance (m)") +
  geom_point(shape=1) +
  facet_grid(vars(analyte), scales = "free")+labs(y="Concentration (mg/L)")+labs(x="Distance(m)")
```

However, I need the Y-axis to begin at 0 and I need to customize the maximum on all three panels. Can someone help me do this?

I have attached a screenshot of what my graphs look like

I'm kind of an R novice so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Try with `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA))` to fix the lower limit at zero while still having a free upper limit for each panel.

Comment: Or use `+ expand_limits(x = 0)`